# How to Animate an Image Into a Circular Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had done this Till nOw  https://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/6146

```
var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;
$("#coolDiv").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
```

Now I want to make it such that
There is a Circualar Div with some border just like in the jsfiddle link

& 3 Flowers Images should be already there.

and one flower image animate or dropped at some random place within that circular div.

Hope So You Got the Point.

Comment: your jsfiddle link not working.

Comment: Question unclear. Please re-phrase.

Comment: Are you looking for a black bordered circle, with the 3 flower images inside it. With a 4th flower image, moving into a random place within the circle from some random place on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The `jquery` should be something like this.Hope this helps.
Click [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0gmdz6mu/) to find the fiddle

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coolDiv").animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow");
    $("#coolDiv").animate({"right":"493px"}, "slow");
    $("#coolDiv").animate({"top":"26px"}, "slow");
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a dumyy. Try with this animation, working fine here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  

  for(i=0; i < 100; i++){
    var animate = $('#coolDiv');
    animate.animate({left:'98%'}, 1000);
    animate.animate({top:'75%'}), 1000;
    animate.animate({left:'0'}), 1000;
    animate.animate({top:'0'}), 1000;
  }
  
})
```

```css
#coolDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
.round {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="round" id="main" style="border:2px solid black;">
  <div style="margin:25px;">
    <img id="img_id" src="http://i.imgur.com/TLqV50g.jpg" width="20px" height="20px;" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLqV50g.jpg" width="20px" height="20px;" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLqV50g.jpg" width="20px" height="20px;" />
  </div>
  <div id="coolDiv">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLqV50g.jpg" width="20px" height="20px;" />
  </div>
</div>
    


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```